# Ipython notebook will not start on command line

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I tried to open ipython in terminal with `ipython notebook` and it will not open ipython notebook. It gives the following error:

```
| ~/documents/ud120-projects/datasets_questions @ HJ (JiaHui)
| => ipython notebook
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and 
will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in 
the future
[I 14:46:50.516 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: 
/Users/JiaHui/Documents/ud120-projects/datasets_questions
[I 14:46:50.517 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 14:46:50.517 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: 
http://localhost:8888/?token=ef13f681f4d61223064e41a5a9e369813c155d27b0103471
[I 14:46:50.517 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down 
all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:46:51.567 NotebookApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?
token=ef13f681f4d61223064e41a5a9e369813c155d27b0103471
0:97: execution error: "http://localhost:8888/tree?
token=145eccd35722c35c6525d8a4d376f27aa60358dc7d00de4c" doesn’t understand the 
“open location” message. (-1708)
```

I have upgraded conda jupyter but it still won't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: btw, I have also used jupyter notebook on cmd, it gives the same error.

Comment: Discussed and solved on the [Jupyter GitHub forums](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438) and in [this blog post](http://www.andrewjaffe.net/blog/2017/05/python-bug-hunt.html).

Comment: I followed the answer with Kiem Nguyen, but the last step I copied the 'c.NotebookApp.browser = u'chrome' ' from the answer instead of adding 'chrome' to the file. Then I succeeded.

Answer (score 23):

This issue due to the newest Mac OSX 10.12.5 upgrade. Please follow these steps to fix it:

1. Generate jupyter config if you don't have it:
   jupyter notebook --generate-config
2. Use vim to open that config file and add Google chrome value in:
   c.NotebookApp.browser = u'chrome' (Make sure to take out the # comment sign)

Comment: Or `c.NotebookApp.browser = u'Safari'` (and remove the hashtag) for those who use Safari.

Comment: Thanks, Works for me !

Comment: Not working here, I get the following error: ```No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.```

Comment: @ ricoamor. It worked for me by replacing the apostrophe. It was in the wrong format.

Answer (score 3):

I used the same approach as Kiem Nguyen above, but 'chrome' wouldn't work for me, even after editing my .bash_profile as Hanshenry90 suggested.

To use Safari to view the notebook, open your terminal and enter:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
cd ~.jupyter
nano jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

ctrl + w "NotebookApp.browser" + enter to skip to that part of the file. Then delete `#` and change the line to:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'Safari'
```

Restart your notebook, with `jupyter notebook`, and it should open in Safari.

If anyone has any insight on how to make this work for Chrome, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Kiem Nguyen's approach didn't work for Chrome for me. Also Hanshenry's edit to the .bash_profile didn't fix for Chrome. I also attempted entering in 'Google Chrome' and 'Chrome' instead. It was not recognized as a legitimate browser.

Comment: Hi, Victor Vulovic. Could you try to update your Chrome and your MacOS to the latest versions? Please also make sure you saved the config file after you changed it. I tested and my solution worked on 3 different Macs, it also works well for others. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Kiem, I made to sure to update both-- no change unfortunately. It could be due to some other software dependencies in my environment.

Answer (score 2):

I liked most [imarti's](https://github.com/lmarti) [solution](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438#issuecomment-305236855):

```
export BROWSER=open
```

It is low overhead and works with your default browser

**EDIT:** macOS 10.12.6 has been released, so now the recommended solution is to just update your OS.

Comment: Very clever solution and the most macOS friendly!

Comment: @MonsieurDart Of course now it's best to just update your macOS

Answer (score 1):

editing my `nano .bash_profile file` to contain the lines:

```
BROWSER=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
export BROWSER
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best fix, but a potential workaround...

Go to your browser and enter the login token provided. 
In your case: http://localhost:8888/

After starting a new notebook, I found that my kernel would die and be unable to restart. Updating my ipykernel fixed this:

`pip install ipykernel --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue possibly due to the recent upgrade of Mac OSX. You can follow the discussion and possible solutions [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438), [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5376) and [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1745).