# Execution error: Can't open jupyter notebook on command line (MacOS)

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am a novice just starting to learn Python and other computer languages. I installed Jupiter notebook on my Mac and also anaconda and just encountered a problem when I tried to open jupyter notebook on my command.

The message popped out as :

```
execution error: "~~~(I just abbreviated the location)" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)
```

I have no sense what's happening here.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ipython notebook will not start on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057601/ipython-notebook-will-not-start-on-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been solved in the [jupyter notebook github repo](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438).

One solution would be to set you browser, for instance:

`c.NotebookApp.browser = u'Safari'`

in the config file: `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Comment: If the file isn't present, you can generate it by doing: `jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question on SO that addresses this. There are couple of workaround that are suggested there to avoid this issue:

[Ipython notebook will not start on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057601/ipython-notebook-will-not-start-on-command-line)

Also, it is a known issue that may be due to a recent upgrade of Mac OSX. You can follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438), [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5376) and [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1745).

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to use the automator tool app for Mac to open both Chrome and jupyter notebook at the same time. Here's the applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "jupyter notebook"
    end tell
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        open location "http://localhost:8888/"
    end tell

end run
```

Hopefully this helps!
Here is a good URL on how to use Automator if you have not used it in the past: http://radarearth.com/content/automate-terminal-automator

Answer (score 0):

export BROWSER=/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome