# I can not use jupyter notebook suddenly

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I can not use jupyter notebook suddenly. I just updated the system of my mac, before I started notebook. Following is the error.

```
[W 21:44:52.515 NotebookApp] server_extensions is deprecated, use nbserver_extensions
[I 21:44:52.964 NotebookApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.2.5
[I 21:44:52.968 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/william/Folders/jupyter
[I 21:44:52.968 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 21:44:52.968 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=159e4e1df709b7a94adb260448f671b9f9689d7b9b388fc5
[I 21:44:52.968 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 21:44:52.973 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=159e4e1df709b7a94adb260448f671b9f9689d7b9b388fc5
0:97: execution error: “"http://localhost:8888/tree?token=f0ef33a1f3bc91981dfe0dca2c1479a3cd718e775ea33c23"” dosen't understand information “open location”。 (-1708)
```

Comment: Have you tried to search for similar questions on stackoverflow ? This one seems similar to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057601/ipython-notebook-will-not-start-on-command-line

Comment: Yes Thank you. why did not i find the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to MAC upgrade to 10.12.5. To fix the issue follow below steps

- Step1: Open the terminal and go to `~/.jupyter` folder
- Step2: Create a config file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` and write the following command inside it and save the file in the same location:
    `c.NotebookApp.browser = u'safari'`
- Step3: Come out and in terminal type `jupyter notebook`, it should work now.